# SAS adding filter

Tags: sas

I'm trying to get the row count for multiples tables but only for the latest date.
The code below is giving the row count by table (no filter). How can I get just the record count for the latest date?

```
proc sql;
select cats("&libname..",memname)
   into :tables separated by ' '
   from dictionary.tables
   where libname=upcase("&libname.");
quit;

data counts;
set &tables. indsname=ds_name end=eof; 
retain count dataset_name;
if _n_=1 then count=0;
if ds_name ne lag(ds_name) and _n_ ne 1 then do;
   output;
   count=0;
end;
dataset_name=ds_name;
count = count+1;  
if eof then output;
keep count dataset_name;
run;
```

Comment: Is the date part of the dataset name?  If so, please provide an example table name.

Comment: Yes, so i have about 40 tables and 20 of them have the date column, so I wanna applied the filter for these tables and do nothing for the tables that don't have this column.

Comment: Ok, we will assume your table names are all different.  What is the name of the date column?

Comment: DATE is the name of the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the below code runs as is... feel free to copy/paste and run it on your system to see the results.

I would start by using the `dictionary.columns` table to find just the tables you are looking for.  The only field we need to keep from each table is the `date` field.  This is needed to avoid any conflicts (in case the same field name as been defined as both char and numeric in different tables).

```
proc sql noprint;
  select distinct cats(libname,'.',memname,'(keep=date)')
  into :tables separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname eq "SASHELP"
    and upcase(name) eq "DATE"
  ;
quit;

%put &tables;
```

Gives:

> SASHELP.AIR(keep=date) SASHELP.BUY(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.CITIDAY(keep=date) SASHELP.CITIMON(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.CITIQTR(keep=date) SASHELP.CITIWK(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.CITIYR(keep=date) SASHELP.GNGSMP2(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.GNP(keep=date) SASHELP.NVST1(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.NVST2(keep=date) SASHELP.NVST3(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.NVST4(keep=date) SASHELP.NVST5(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.PRDSAL3(keep=date) SASHELP.PRICEDATA(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.RENT(keep=date) SASHELP.RETAIL(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.ROCKPIT(keep=date) SASHELP.SNACKS(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.STEEL(keep=date) SASHELP.STOCKS(keep=date)
>   SASHELP.USECON(keep=date) SASHELP.WORKERS(keep=date)

Next, use a view to concatenate all the tables together.  I would have liked to have skipped this step but found it wasn't possible to do this and use the keep/by-group-processing/indsname options all at once.  If your tables are small you may want to output just a regular dataset rather than a view.

```
data tmp / view=tmp;
  set &tables indsname=ds_name; 
  dataset_name=ds_name;
run;
```

Use `by-group` processing to keep track of the number of records for the last date in each table.  This assumes that the last date is also the maximum date (you may need to check this in your data).

```
data want;
  set tmp; 
  by dataset_name ;

  retain count dataset_name;

  if first.dataset_name then do; 
    count=0;
  end;

  count = count+1;  

  if last.dataset_name then do;
     output;
  end;
  keep count date dataset_name;
run;
```

Final output:

```
Obs DATE  dataset_name    count  
1   DEC60 SASHELP.AIR     144  
2   JAN06 SASHELP.BUY     11  
3   FEB92 SASHELP.CITIDAY 1069  
4   JAN92 SASHELP.CITIMON 145  etc...
```